# Casting a C# String to a date type that matches Oracle;s date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

I'm trying to write Oracle SQL queries executed via a C#/ASP.NET program to insert data into an Oracle Db. I'm having problems finding a C# method that would cast a string (coming from a form's user input in format 11/11/2012) to match Oracle's date data type. I tried to cast it via the [Convert.ToDateTime(object) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky38w316.aspx) without any success.

Here's my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<script runat="server">

   void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

       //Get user's input form form fields
       var saleID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["saleID_aspx"]);
       var custID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["custID_aspx"]);
       var agentID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["agentID_aspx"]);
       var saleDate = Convert.ToDateTime("11/11/2012"); //Originally Request.Form["saleDate_aspx"]
       var homeID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["homeID_aspx"]);
       var actualAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["actualAmount_aspx"]);
       var contractID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["contractID_aspx"]);
       var valueCommand = "VALUES(" + saleID + "," + custID + "," + agentID + "," + saleDate + "," + contractID + "," + homeID + "," + actualAmount + ")";
      // Declaration section
      OleDbConnection objDBConn;
      OleDbCommand    objCmd;
      OleDbCommand objCmdSelect;
      OleDbDataReader objDR;

      // Set up OLE DB Connection object
      objDBConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=*****1;" +
                                      "User ID=********;" +
                                      "Password=*******;" +
                                      "Data Source=****");


      // Open DB connection
      objDBConn.Open();

      // Create OleDbCommand object with SQL to execute
      objCmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sale (saleID, cust_ID, agent_ID, saleDate, contractID, homeID, actualamount)" +
            valueCommand, objDBConn);


      // Create a DataReader and execute the command
      objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

      // Copy results from DataReader to DataGrid object
      gridCusts.DataSource = objDR;
      gridCusts.DataBind();

      // Close all objects
      objDR.Close();
      objCmd.Dispose();

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // Create OleDbCommand object with SQL to execute
      objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * " +
                                "  FROM Sale " +
                                " ORDER BY saleID", objDBConn);

      // Create a DataReader and execute the command
      objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

      // Copy results from DataReader to DataGrid object
      gridCusts.DataSource = objDR;
      gridCusts.DataBind();

      // Close all objects
      objDR.Close();
      objCmdSelect.Dispose();
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
      objDBConn.Close();        
   }

</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>CUSTOMERS table</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Oracle SALES table contents via C#.NET and OLE DB</h2>
        <div style="margin:0 auto text-align:center;">
            <asp:DataGrid id="gridCusts" class='table' runat="server" />
        </div>
        <a href="index.html" target="_self" class="btn">Go Back</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the formatof your date in string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the oracle function `to_date`.

```
var valueCommand = "VALUES(" + saleID + "," + custID + "," + agentID + ", 
    to_date('" + saleDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "', 'mm/dd/yyyy')," + contractID + "," + homeID + "," + actualAmount + ")";
```

Comment: Great! That worked just fine, thank you very much! I actually slightly simplified your code as follows:var saleDate = Request.Form["saleDate_aspx"];  var valueCommand = "VALUES(" + saleID + "," + custID + "," + agentID + ", to_date('" + saleDate + "', 'mm/dd/yyyy')," + contractID + "," + homeID + "," + actualAmount + ")";

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many issues in your code that cause to failure of your program.

1. Hardcoded SQL string which causes [type conversion, escaping and SQL Injection issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx). [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)
2. Selection of Command methods - When to use ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader? Call `ExecuteNonQuery()` method to execute SQL statements other than `SELECT`.
3. Improper way to dispose the database resourecs. Use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block. (SO Threads - [What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it) and [C# - closing Sql objects best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328005/c-sharp-closing-sql-objects-best-practice).